# How to count based on group?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working with a medium sized data set, and i have three columns, department name, email, and completion

My end goal is to graph this data with pandas, so im trying to figure out the best way possible

I have done this with pivot tables, but i need to calculate two things that include the department name. First is the number of employees within that department and 2nd how many people completed the training within that department (then i plan to do a bar graph with this data)

For example

```
Finance email6@domain.com Complete
IT  email1@domain.com   
IT  email2@domain.com Complete
IT  email3@domain.com Complete
Accounting  email4@domain.com   
Accounting  email5@domain.com    Complete
Accounting  email6@domain.com    Complete
```

so output for IT would have 3 employees and 2 completed that training

Id like to know how many people there are in IT and how many people completed it in IT, finance, accounting, ect.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: So, if training is not complete, what is the value entered in thr 3rd column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby with aggregate

```
df.groupby('department name').completion.agg({'Total_Employees':'size', 'Completed_training':'count'})

                Total_Employees Completed_training
department name     
Accounting      3               2
Finance         1               1
IT              3               2
```

The idea being size returns the size of the group whereas count returns count of nonNaN values.

To create barplot, you can simply use pandas plot()

```
df.groupby('department name').completion.agg({'Total_Employees':'size', 'Completed_training':'count'}).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Edit:

Given the column names ['Department', 'Email', 'Completion'], the code would be

```
df.groupby('Department').Completion.agg({'Total_Employees':'size', 'Completed_training':'count'}).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: can i publish this in a webpage?

Comment: Yeah, this is a pretty standard solution

Comment: how would you assign the variables from a csv? i have this:df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\dbeiler\\Desktop\\F5\\PythonApplication1\\PythonApplication1\\SANS.xlsx', data = ['Department', 'Email', 'Completion'])

Comment: I am not sure if I get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: how do you correlate the df.groupby with my csv file? how do you assign the coloumn values to variables?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
department = ['Finance', 'IT', 'IT', 'IT', 'Accounting', 'Accounting', 'Accounting']
status = ['Complete', 'Incomplete', 'Complete', 'Complete', 'Incomplete', 'Complete','Complete']
email = ['email6@domain.com', 
         'email1@domain.com',
         'email2@domain.com',
         'email3@domain.com',
         'email4@domain.com',
         'email5@domain.com',
         'email6@domain.com']

df101 = pd.DataFrame({'Dep' : department, 'Email': email, 'Status': status})
grouped = df101.groupby(['Dep', 'Status']).count().fillna(0)

# output
                      Email
Dep         Status  
Accounting  Complete    2
            Incomplete  1
Finance     Complete    1
IT          Complete    2
            Incomplete  1


grouped.unstack().plot.bar(stacked = True)
#output
```

Comment: this is all from a csv, any easy way to do it if the top lines say Department, email address, and completion?

Comment: yes instead of 'Dep' and 'Status' use 'Department' and 'Completion'. Also please accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\dbeiler\\Desktop\\F5\\PythonApplication1\\PythonApplication1\\SANS.xlsx', data = ['Department', 'Email', 'Completion'])
print df.head()

df101 = pd.DataFrame({'Department' : department, 'Email': email, 'Completion': status})
grouped = df101.groupby(['Dep', 'Status']).count().fillna(0)

print df

Comment: NameError: name 'department' is not defined

Comment: I created 'department' variable, which is a list, for your data sake. Is the df reading from excel just follow the lines of codes for your DataFrame (df) from the grouped line. In your case it will be, grouped = df.groupby(['Department' , 'Completion']).count().fillna(0)

Then:

grouped.unstack().plot.bar(stacked = True)